# Resource Provider for AKS Backup Vault

Tags: azure, azure-aks

What is Resource Provider for AKS Backup Vault ?

Is it "Microsoft.ContainerService" OR "Microsoft.DataProtection" OR "Microsoft.BackupVault" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, AKS backup requires Trusted Access to be enabled between the AKS cluster and the Backup vault. Trusted Access allows the Backup vault to access the AKS cluster because of specific permissions that are assigned to it for backup operations. To enable Trusted Access, the Resource Provider for the AKS cluster must be "Microsoft.ContainerService".

To clarify:

- When talking about the management of the backup vault itself and its policies in Azure, the correct resource provider is `Microsoft.DataProtection`.
- When referring to the AKS cluster and the need to establish Trusted Access for backup operations, `Microsoft.ContainerService` is involved because it is the resource provider for AKS.

In summary, for the AKS Backup Vault functionality, you would be dealing with both `Microsoft.DataProtection` for backup vault management and `Microsoft.ContainerService` for AKS-related configurations and Trusted Access.

Reason?

1. The *Resource Provider for AKS Backup Vault* pertains to the service that manages the backup vault itself, which is typically associated with data protection and backup services in Azure. As such, it is managed by the `Microsoft.DataProtection` resource provider if you are using the Azure Backup service for AKS.
2. *Trusted Access between AKS and Backup vault*: The documentation reference is correct in stating that you need Trusted Access between the AKS cluster and the Backup vault. Trusted Access does indeed involve the AKS resource provider, `Microsoft.ContainerService`, because it pertains to the AKS cluster itself. This allows the Backup vault, managed by `Microsoft.DataProtection`, to access the AKS cluster to perform backup operations.

Reference:
[Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) backup using Azure Backup prerequisites - Azure Backup | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/azure-kubernetes-service-cluster-backup-concept#trusted-access)